# Customizing Woocommerce

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to create a quick view function for woocommerce. I'm using fancybox to create a pop up when the button is clicked on the archive product loop page. I let fancybox load an iframe of the product page and prevent scrolling so it only shows the product image, summary and thumbnails. However, the menu and nav are showing at the top. I want to show only the product summary without the header and nav.

This is the code I use.

Here is the HTML

```
<a id="quickview" class="iframe" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">+ Quick View</a>
```

Here is the JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//Quick View        
$("#quickview").fancybox({
    'width': 1000,
    'height': 600,
    fitToView: false,
    autoSize: false,
    'closeBtn': true,
    'scrolling': 'no',
    'type':'iframe',
    'iframe': {'scrolling': 'no'}
    });     
});
```

I tried using the method below but it doesn't work. It does load the product page without the header but without css and the archive product loop breaks.

```
<a id="quickview" href="#data">+ Quick View</a>

<div style="display:none">
<div id="data">
<?php woocommerce_before_single_product_summary(); ?>
<?php woocommerce_single_product_summary(); ?>
</div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Interesting. Did you setting `display:none` for the header/navigation inside the iframe?